# How do I check if a string is a valid integer?

Tags: stanza

Let's say I have

```
val s = "123"
val r = "a123h"
```

How do I check if `s` can be resolved to a valid integer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The signature of `to-int` in the package `core` is

```
public lostanza defn to-int (s:ref<String>) -> ref<False|Int>
```

So you need :

```
defn is-int? (s: String) -> True|False :
  to-int(s) is Int
```

N.B.: `to-int` accepts hexadecimal `0x...`, octal `0o...`  and binary `0b...` string representations in addition to decimal ones.